# Android Pusher java.io.FileNotFoundException: when trying to set Authorizer the Authenticating API call not reaching the server

Tags: android, kotlin, pusher

I'm trying to use pusher channels for real-time features im trying to subscribe to a private channel but the authenticating API is not reaching our servers even though it is working from front-end side but not form Android side i have the latest version of the pusher SDK and i double checked the App Key and Cluster

[image]
[image]

these are the photos from the profiler:
[image]

[image]

Edited: added Error Log

[image]

```
fun getMapAuthorizationHeaders(token: String): HashMap<String, String> {
        val authHeader = HashMap<String, String>()
        authHeader["Accept"] = "application/json"
        authHeader["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token"
        //authHeader["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        return authHeader
    }
```

Comment: Where possible please paste the code instead of using images.

Could you share the full error when the subscription fails?

Comment: @doydoy i added the logs when the error happens  sorry for image spamming

Comment: You should check your Android device is able to reach your auth endpoint and that the auth endpoint can accept POST requests. The error suggests the auth endpoint is not present at the URL provided